# what does exactly query() return in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Code Igniter Model contains following two methods.

```
public function generate_uuid() {
    return "it is returning SOME unique ID";
}

public function getUniqueIdentifier()
{
    $Uuid = '';                               
    $checkStatus=true;
    while($checkStatus)
    {
        $Uuid = $this->generate_uuid();
        $checkQry2 = "select * from Leads where controllNumber=".$this->db->escape($Uuid);
        $checkRes2 = $this->db->query($checkQry2);

        $checkRes2 = $checkRes2->num_rows();
        if($checkRes2 === 0)
        {
            $checkStatus=false;
        }


    }
    return $Uuid;
}
```

I've imported this model on the controller and calling if from some method of that controller?

```
$this->modObject->getUniqueIdentifier();
```

> Error  Message:  Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Can anybody help? thank you.

Comment: Some problem that i observed at db side is that the "controllNumber" column is there in the Leads table. This leads to null in the  $checkRes2 varible when I run the query.

Answer (score 1):

Query method returns false if MySQL bridge returns errors. 
EDIT: Perhaps you forgot to surround by single quotes the $this->db->escape($Uuid) as it returns a string.

I suggest you to use CodeIgniter's Query Builder as it's way more secure.

You query would be like:

```
$this->db->from('Leads');
$this->db->where('controllNumber', $Uuid); // No need to escape
$results = $this->db->get()->result();

if ( !empty($results) ) {
    $num_rows = count($results);
    // Do your stuff
} else {
    // No rows returned
}
```

Greetings

Comment: Not precisely correct. `get()`, `get_where()`, and `query()` return 'false' if the query fails. Zero rows is not a query failure. On success, the functions return an instance of `CI_DB_result`.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I edited my answer. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

On "read" type database operations `query()` returns an object (of type `CI_DB_result`) on success or the boolean `false` if the query fails. In this context, a query that produces no rows is not a failure.

It appears to me that `getUniqueIdentifier()` is to return a unique ident if the value generated by `generate_uuid()` is not already being used in the database. If it is already used it should return `false`.  The following will accomplish that.

Here we use the [Query Binding](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) of the `query()` method to assure safely escaped values.

```
public function getUniqueIdentifier()
{
    $Uuid = $this->generate_uuid();
    $sql = "select * from Leads where controllNumber = ?";  //two 'l' in 'controll'?
    $checkRes = $this->db->query($sql, array($Uuid));

    //If the query did not fail and we retrieved no rows return the unique id
    if($checkRes && $checkRes->num_rows() === 0)
    {
         return $Uuid;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Instead of asking for all columns (i.e. `select * ...'`) asking for a single column (i.e. `'select controllNumber ...'` will likely produce a faster query.